# Problem while opening a file because of weird characters on the file path

Tags: c, file, fopen

I'm reading the path of some file from a file given as arguments to my application. 
Each path is written on a line. I have problem with the last path which give me this error:

```
Cannot open C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\find\try1.txtl¹v
```

Here's my code:

```
    struct filePath{
        char path[255];
        int fileOccurences;
    };

    struct filePath fPath[2];
    char currentLine[255];
    char path[255];
    char word[30];
    int i, ch;
    int k = 0;
    FILE * fInput = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
    if(fInput == NULL){ //check sull'apertura del file
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s, exiting. . .\n", argv[1]);
       exit(1);
    }

    while(!feof(fInput)){
        for (i = 0; (i < (sizeof(path)-1) && ((ch = fgetc(fInput)) != EOF) && (ch != '\n')); i++){
            fPath[k].path[i] = ch;
        }
        FPath[k].path[i] = '\0';
        k = k + 1;
    }
    fclose(fInput);
    for(int j = 0; j<2; j++){
        FILE * fp = fopen(fPath[j].path, "r"); 
        if(fp == NULL){ 
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s, exiting. . .\n", fPath[j].path);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I have upload only the interested part of the program, this isn't how i exactly wrote my code. So, someone know how can i solve this problem and cancel these character "l¹v". Thank you.

Comment: How are you running your program? Can you give an example of what you type on the command line? Also, can you fix the errors in your code. I cannot compile and run it as it is in this question, primarily because you have no `main()`.

Comment: Is this message coming because `fInput` is NULL or because `fp` is NULL?

Comment: Also, change the error message. In that way, we know where the error occurred.

Comment: Are you reading the paths in a `while (!feof(Input))` loop?  Don't do that.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: In the error message, don't just say "Cannot open file".  Give the reason.  `man perror` and `man strerror`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read the file names character by character into `fPath[k].path[i]`, then set `path[i]` to nul after the loop.
But `fPath[k].path` and `path` are not the same variable, so you haven't null-terminated `fPath[k].path[i]`